# Creating multiple form to insert number

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I have a form which is super simple.

```
<input type="text" name="tel">
```

So basically user hits submit and save new record with only the Tel.

what i want is to allow the user to create many tel row in the database. I have found a few different way of doing this and would like to know which approach is the best.

1)  is to duplicate my form and increment the number which means i would need to write a lot of code.

```
<input type="text" name="tel">
<input type="text" name="tel1">
<input type="text" name="tel2">
<input type="text" name="tel3">
```

submit would create 4 new rows but this method would create allot of coding for its intended purpose.

2) I found a few references to using a class but i haven't got the slightest idea where to start with classes.

is there a simpler way of achieving this or is option 1 my best bet?

Comment: Try <input type="text" name="tel[]"> <input type="text" name="tel[]"> ....... and access it as array from PHP

Comment: what is problem? Do it like  @Nouphal.M proposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this.

```
<input type="text" name="tel[]">
<input type="text" name="tel[]">
<input type="text" name="tel[]">
<input type="text" name="tel[]">
```

and on server side you can extract them as array.

```
foreach($_POST['tel'] as $tel=>$value)
{
   echo $tel.' - '.$value;
}
```